# MarkLogic MLCP tool fails to run SSL on port 8000

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am able to open admin/QConsole GUI with SSL on (Secure Sockets Layer).  But the MLCP fails to run on port 8000 with SSL on.  I have to turn off SSL in order for the MLCP to work.

How can I setup MLCP to work with SSL?

I am currently using Marklogic version 8.0-7 and mlcp-8.0-5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With version 9, MLCP has options available to enable SSL:

### [Configuring mlcp to Use SSL](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/install#id_51800)

> By default, mlcp does not connect to MarkLogic using SSL. Use one of the following options to specify that mlcp should connect via SSL:

<kbd><kbd><kbd>**`mlcp Command`**</kbd>

  <kbd>`import`</kbd>

  <kbd>`export`</kbd>

  <kbd>`copy`</kbd></kbd>


  <kbd><kbd>**`Command Line Option`**</kbd>

  <kbd>`-ssl`</kbd>

  <kbd>`-ssl`</kbd>
 
  <kbd>`-input_ssl and/or -output_ssl`</kbd></kbd> 


  <kbd><kbd>**`For more information`**</kbd>

  <kbd>`Import Command Line Options`</kbd>

  <kbd>`Export Command Line Options`</kbd>

  <kbd>`Copy Command Line Options`</kbd></kbd></kbd>

> All these options accept a boolean argument value. As described in [Command Line Summary](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/intro#id_79450), 'true' is assumed if you leave the argument off.